# Joomla - ChronoForm: Submit action based on user selection

Tags: php, paypal, joomla, chronoforms

I am new to Joomla and Chronoform.

Site is integrated with chronoform 5 and it accepts payment via paypal pro and check. User has option to select paypal or check for payment as shown below

[image]

I have completed payment through paypal onsubmit. But if use selects check it should not process payment and also it should give different display message. How I can integrate both ? Please suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an Event Switcher action after the form submits to redirect to different pages for the different payment methods.

Please see [this FAQ](http://www.chronoengine.com/faqs/70-cfv5/5255-how-can-i-switch-form-pages-in-cfv5) for an example of using the Event Switcher.

Comment: Can you be more specific, I do not know how to setup a event switcher actually.

Comment: I updated my Answer to include a link to a FAQ on using the Event Switcher.